# Sorting an list of type `List<Iterable<Object>>`

Tags: java, collections, interface, comparable, iterable

I have a list of type `List<Iterable<Object>>` and in some case the objects that are inside the collection are also `Comparable`.

That means that in some cases it is a list that contains many objects of type A that is not `Comparable`, in some other cases it contains many objects of type B that are `Comparable`. When I have a list of objects of type B, I want to be able to sort them.

When all the objects inside the list are `Comparable` I need to sort them, using `Collections.sort()` or something similar. Java does not allow me to cast the entire list, and I can't cast single elements, because they may not implement the `Comparable` interface. Is there a work around?

If it is useful, this is my code:

```
    Iterable<Object> iterable;

    List<Iterable<Object>> valori = new ArrayList<Iterable<Object>>();

    Integer valoriLetti = 0;

    iterable = new ArrayList<Object>();
    while (iterable != null && valoriLetti < numero) {
        // Object object = beanReader.read();
        try {
            iterable = (Iterable<Object>) beanReader.read();
        } catch (InvalidRecordException ex) {

            log.error(this.toString());
            log.error(ex);
            log.error(ex.getStackTrace());
        }

        if (iterable != null) {
            ((IEntityAmount) iterable).moltiplicaImporti();
            ((IEntityAmount) iterable).troncaImporti();
            valori.add(iterable);
            valoriLetti += 1;

            // if (iterable.iterator().hasNext()) {
            // valori.add(leggiValori(iterable));
            // valoriLetti += 1;
            // }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want your objects sorted?

Comment: There's no way that this would even make sense unless all the elements are comparable.  What are you _actually_ trying to do?  If we knew what your real use case was, we might be able to help you figure out something that _does_ make sense.

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry I did not explain myself. In some cases the List contains many objects of type A that is not Comparable. In other cases the List contains many objects of type B that is Comparable.

Comment: @Keppil I am not sure that I have understood your question. I want them to be sorted according to the `compareTo()` method that I already have implemented.

Comment: @Vitalij: Before your edit your question stated that they may not implement Comparable, hence my question. I see you got the answer you were looking for, so all is well.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: In the case where any list contains any objects that are not comparable, sorting doesn't make sense, unless you have a custom comparator that can compare those objects.  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer explains how you can cast a `Collection<A>` to `Collection<B>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651086/1428461