# Casting One Collection Type to another Collection Type and iterate over it in Java

Tags: java, casting

I have a wrapper layer which returns me a Collection of objects of certain Type. Now I call this wrapper in my application which has a different type, so I try to cast the whole collection that is been returned into my application type.

```
Collection<wrapperType> wrapperCollection = wrapper.method();
MyApp<appType> appCollection = (Collection<appType>)wrapperCollection;
```

Above casts wrapperCollection to appCollection. Now when i try to do this-:

```
for( appType item : appCollection) // Exception-: can't convert wrapperType to appType.
{
.......
}
```

I am trying to figure out-:

- How can I cast wrapperCollection to appCollection so that each item inside the appCollection becomes appType and then I can iterate over it? Is there any other better way via which I can easily cast ans Iterate over collection.
- I am also thinking is casting a good idea at all performance wise.

I researched following links-:

[Cast a Collection to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651030/java-cast-collection-type-to-subtypefor(%20appType%20item%20:%20appCollection)%20//%20Exception-:%20can't%20convert%20wrapperType%20to%20appType.%20%7B%20..........%20%7D)

Comment: Please show us the signature for `MyApp`, `wrapperType`, and `appType`

Comment: wrapperType and appType contains mostly same fields like personId, name etc. appType has few more fields that can be populated further via MyApp.

Comment: Clearly `wrapperCollection` contains something that's not an `appType`. (Perhaps you need to learn more about inheritance and casting in general here...?) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: please remember to mark your question as answered if a solution suits your problem.

Comment: sure, I am still working on it. More likely to follow generics approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use either a generic collection, or define a parent class (mostly an interface or abstract class) which both class extends/implements. Then store your object as list of this parent class instead.

Note that if you choose to use generics, both type must be compatible. Example :

```
List<? extends Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Number i : intList)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys. I ended up using generics as Jean-Francois / Turing85 suggested. I also gave an attempt to create a base class which both wrapperType and appType can extend. Issue with that is wrapper is a layer which eventually going to be consumed by various applications, so I am not sure where base class would reside? PS: don't have enough points to vote up answers, though I marked which was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a `Collection<WrapperType>` into a `Collection<appType>` or vice-versa. One reason this is not possible is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754756/how-to-cast-a-list-of-inheriting-objects-to-a-collection-of-objects-in-java). If you want to achieve your goal, you need to do this manually, i.e. iterate over the `Collection<WrapperType>`, cast each entry into an object of type `appType` and add them to a new `Collection<appType>`

EDIT: look at @Jean-François Savard's answer for a workaround. This is also known as [PECS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_%28Java%29)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can refactor your code to something like below.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericWrap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? super String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("hello");
    myList.add("world");
    for(String s : (List<String>)myList){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without using any framework / library, then you must do it "by hand" (read: manually). If you can get the help of "something" already built for this purposes, try [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/); it's (almost) the perfect tool for doing that kind of stuff.